# Get apollo-server authentication cookie in react

Tags: reactjs, authentication, cookies, session-cookies, react-apollo

I don't understand how to get the session cookie on the apollo client in react. I know how to create it, and it works fine with login/logout. The session cookie is stored with the name "sid". Credentials are set to "include".

Now the only problem I have is, I want to check if the user is already logged in. I already check it on the server-side, but have no clue how to do it on the client side.

Thank you very much in advance!

```
Client setup:
// Client for GraphQl
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  credentials: "include"
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
            <ApolloProvider client={client}>
              <Navbar />
            </ApolloProvider>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Edit: Problem solved. I forgot to set the httpOnly to false, otherwise, you can't read the cookie via JavaScript.